# Accessing Item property using C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289500%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

It works fine but then often I see `Item` in the VB version

However, `button.Item` doesn't exist in C#, but when I open a new project and try in VB.NET I get `Item`. Why is that and how can I use `Item` in C#?

**Visual Basic**

```
Default Public ReadOnly Property Item(ByVal Index As Integer) As _
   System.Windows.Forms.Button
   Get
      Return CType(Me.List.Item(Index), System.Windows.Forms.Button)
   End Get
End Property
```

**C#**

```
public System.Windows.Forms.Button this [int Index]
{
get
   {
      return (System.Windows.Forms.Button) this.List[Index];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invoking the "Item" in C# can be done with the squared brackets:

```
var myButton = myButtonsArray[0];
```

The "[]" brackets are actually invoking the indexer which is called "Item" in VB.